# Do transformers need to be derated with increasing altitude?

Tags: transformer

Does a transformer power or VA specification need to be derated with increasing altitude above sea level?

Are there other relevant factors affected by increasing altitude?

Comment: Welcome! High voltage for mains grid or small low voltage one in a product?

Comment: 13.8 kva to 400 volt

Comment: If above 2000 meter above sea level, there is IEC derating on voltage withstand for any high voltage connections. Once on the inside of the transformer (oil), the windings won't care voltage-wise. On top of that, air cooling needs derating too. Is that what you asked about?

Comment: Is capacity affected?

Comment: Suppose we have a transformer with a capacity of 1 mega. Does this value decrease in height?

Comment: 1 mega? 1 MVA? Air cooling suffers. Ask the manufacturer for a datasheet?

Comment: Capacity or capacitance or power/VA rating? Which are you talking about?

Comment: I will order the data sheet from the factory, thank you

Comment: The higher you go the more VA they cram into a unit of volumne or mass,  but only because airccraft run higher frequencies than terestrial distribution transformers, and satellites higher still.

Comment: If we had a thousand kilovolt transformer at an altitude of 2300, what would its value be?

Comment: @tobalt I hazard that he is asking if transformers are voltage derated with altitude. Above a certain altitude external connections are.

Comment: @Samer almasri - This whould be included in your main question. You also need to add more detail to your query so people can understand what you are asking.

Comment: [This](https://driveconstructor.com/docs/TextBook/System_components/Altitude_and_derating.html) may be of some use. Also [this](https://www.advancedenergy.com/globalassets/resources-root/application-notes/en-lv-power-supplies-for-high-altitude-applications-application-note.pdf). DO NOT use them blindly. Note what they say and apply any parts that are relevant.

Comment: (Downvoters please comment *why*.)

Answer (score 3):

There are two main factors (my experience is from power and distribution transformers):

1. Thermal capacity: with the increase in altitude the air becomes less dense and it makes difference in the convection phenomena, reducing the dissipated heat. The equipment temperature rise will be higher as the altitude increases. Typical rule is to reduce in the design 1K for each 400m above sea level for natural cooled equipment and 1K for each 250m for equipment with forced ventilation (it is in the standards.) The inverse rule for derating is valid, but sometimes it can be difficult to relate the temperature and the rated power.
2. Dielectric properties: as it becomes less dense, air loses its capacity to dielectric insulate as a reduction in the dielectric strength. It is more relevant for dry-type transformers but also play some role in the bushing clearances for oil-filled transformers.